# Grunt vs "Quotes"

Tags: gruntjs

I am just new in Grunt, but I am spending long hours with a simple problem. A single quote is being converted to html entities. How can I avoid this conversion?

Original HTML:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="document.forms['search'].submit(); return false;">Search                      </button>
```

After run grunt:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="document.forms[&apos;search**&apos;].submit(); return false;">Search</button>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said before, I am new in GruntJS, so I am not sure if this is the best solution (I will appreciate further comments).

But, this worked for me:
I installed grunt-string-replace (https://github.com/erickrdch/grunt-string-replace) and added the following code in Gruntfile.js

```
'string-replace': {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'dist/': '**/*.html'                   
            },


            options: {
                replacements: [{
                    pattern: /(&apos;)/ig,
                    replacement: '\''
                  }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

And:

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-string-replace');

grunt.task.run(['X', 'Y', 'Z','string-replace']);